# React: HTML Details toggles uncontrollably when starts open

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the HTML `<details>` tag to create a simple expandable section using semantic html in combination with React.

The `<details><summary></summary></details>` behaviour works great out of the box and for the 1-2% of my users that use IE users that don't get the show-hide nature of the content, it really isn't the end of the world for the content to always be shown for the time being.

My issue comes when using React hooks to hold onto whether the `<details>` panel is open or closed. The basic layout of the React component is as follows:

```
const DetailsComponent = ({startOpen}) => {
  const [open, toggleOpen] = useState(startOpen);

  return (
    <details onToggle={() => toggleOpen(!open)} open={open}>
      <summary>Summary</summary>
      <p>Hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
    </details>
  );
};
```

The reason I need to use the `onToggle` event is to update the `open` state variable to trigger some other javascript in my real world example. I use the `startOpen` prop to decide whether on page render whether the details pane is open or closed.

The expected behaviour happens when I use the component as, `<DetailsComponent startOpen={ false } />`.

However, when is want to start with the pane open on load (`<DetailsComponent startOpen={ true } />`), I can visibly see the pane opening and closing very very quickly over and over again forever.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 2):

I think You should use prevState

```
<details onToggle={() => toggleOpen(prevOpen => !prevOpen )} open={open}>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately this didn't work for me but I think it would generally be better practice for me to use the previous state explicitly inside the toggle open since it's more explicit use of Hooks.

Answer (score 2):

The `<details>` HTML element does not need to be controlled with js because it already has the functionality to be opened and closed. When you pass the `open` attribute and change it in the `ontoggle` event, you are creating an endless event loop because the element is toggled then the open state changes which toggles the element which triggers the `ontoggle` event and so on... The only thing you need is to pass the initial open state.

```
const DetailsComponent = ({startOpen}) => {
  return (
    <details open={startOpen}>
      <summary>Summary</summary>
      <p>Hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
    </details>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I stated that I needed a way of keeping track of the details open/closed state for other logic inside the component. But you are right, the details component does work great out of the box!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I eventually worked out I can monitor the current state by handling `onToggle` and just not use it to set the `open` attribute.

```
export default ({ defaultOpen, summary, children }: DetailsProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(defaultOpen || false);

  return (
    <details open={defaultOpen} onToggle={e => setExpanded((e.currentTarget as HTMLDetailsElement).open)}>
      <summary>
        {expanded ? <ExpandedIcon /> : <CollapsedIcon />}
        {summary}
      </summary>
      {children}
    </details>
  );
};
```

Because `defaultOpen` does not change it does not cause a DOM update, so the HTML control is still in charge of its state.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `onToggle` is called before mount and that's causing an endless loop for the case where it is rendered open. Because that triggers a new toggle event.

One way to avoid it, is to check if the `details` tag is mounted and only toggle once it is mounted. That way you're ignoring the first toggle event.

```js
const DetailsComponent = ({ startOpen }) => {
  const [open, toggleOpen] = useState(startOpen);
  const [isMounted, setMount] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMount(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <details onToggle={() => isMounted && toggleOpen(!open)} open={open}>
      <summary>Summary</summary>
      <p>Hidden content hidden content hidden content</p>
    </details>
  );
};
```

You can find a working demo in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/detailscomponent-react-demo-dchyr).

Comment: This is a good fix for me, not sure if it's overkill for the element but this is something that will definitely come up in code review!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things to consider.

First, when calling `onClick` on details HTML element, we are reading the current open state *before* the change is performed, i.e. we are reading an outdated state.
According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details), it is better to use `toggle` event which is fired *after* the open state is changed:

```
const detailsRef = useRef<HTMLDetailsElement>(null)

const onToggleCallback = useCallback(() => {
  console.log(detailsRef.current?.open)
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  detailsRef.current?.addEventListener('toggle', onToggleCallback)

  return () => {
    detailsRef.current?.removeEventListener('toggle', onToggleCallback)
  }
}, [onToggleCallback])

// [...] details
```

Second, whenever React state `isOpen` is changed and this variable is passed down into `details` element, the `toggle` event is fired *again*. To prevent changing the React state twice and ending up in a state mismatch, we can simply compare the two values and save a new value into the React state only in case it differs:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)

// [...] useRef

const onToggleCallback = useCallback(() => {
  const newValue = detailsRef.current?.open
  
  if (newValue !== undefined && newValue !== isOpen) {
    setIsOpen(newValue)
  }
}, [])

// [...] useEffect

<details ref={detailsRef} open={isOpen}>
  <summary>Open details</summary>
  <div>Details are opened</div>
</details>
```

Fully working example can be found here https://playcode.io/1559702